# C++ pointers to make an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to C++ ... I am playing with pointers ...
This code uses a char ptr as an array .

```
#‎include‬<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    cout << "Playground "<<endl;

    const short max=10;

    char * str=new char ;

    for (short i=0;i<max;i++)
        *(str+i)=char(i+100);

    for (short i=0;i<max;i++)
        cout <<str+i<< char(3) <<endl;

    for(short i=0;i<max;i++)
        delete (str+i);

    return 0;
}
```

---

But I am not sure if delete (str+i) works or not , and why ?
But I think it does not work because I have run the program many times and although the string is printed :

```
Playground
defghijklm
efghijklm
fghijklm
ghijklm
hijklm
ijklm
jklm
klm
lm
m
```

I have this error message

```
try #0
*** Error in `./p': free(): invalid pointer: 0x09d90009 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

try #1
*** Error in `./p': free(): invalid pointer: 0x08453009 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

try #2
*** Error in `./p': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0863c009 ***
Aborted (core dumped)

etc ...
```

Because the invalid pointer keep changing , I have the feeling that the objects has not been deleted or garbage collected and every time I run the code I use another area of the memory ...

Finally I am starting to get why regular array are better ...

*from the beginning a contiguous space in memory is reserved for the data

*not need to worry about delete ...

Those are just my guesses...

Comment: `delete(str)` will free the memory allocated at the original address.  Adding `i` causes the pointer to be invalid.

Comment: You probably want to look at how big the 'string' at `str` is too.  What exactly is `new char` putting there?  Is it a big enough string?  If so, how does the compiler know how big it has to be?  Maybe it is only placing one `char` there, in which case, where are the rest of teh characters going???

Answer (score 3):

You have out of bound access:

```
char* str = new char; // single element
```

should be

```
char* str=new char[max]; // array of char
```

and you have to release memory with

```
delete [] str;
```

but to avoid to manage memory manually, you may use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`

Answer (score 1):

You are only making one dynamic memory allocation, and for just 1 char, but you are deleting dynamically allocated memory multiple times in the last for-loop - you can only do one delete for every new.

Additionally, in the first for-loop you assign new char values to memory outside of what you allocated, which means you are overwriting memory that isn't yours.